# Боковое навигационное меню и в ранних версиях андроида, как?

Tags: menu, android, java

Пример разбираю тот, что указан на официальном сайте [здесь](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) 
Но данный пример работает только начиная с 4 андроида. Что нужно сделать, как это сделать, что бы работало и в более ранних версиях?

Библиотека присутствует:

[image]

Протестировала на 2.3.3. Программа сама открывается, но не полностью. 
Вот лог и скриншоты:

```
    02-27 07:25:54.505: D/dalvikvm(1233): VFY: dead code 0x0022-0042 in Lua/com/sadesign/aligorex/MainActivity;.onOptionsItemSelected (Landroid/view/MenuItem;)Z
02-27 07:25:54.549: I/dalvikvm(1233): Could not find method ua.com.sadesign.aligorex.MainActivity.getActionBar, referenced from method ua.com.sadesign.aligorex.MainActivity.setTitle
02-27 07:25:54.549: W/dalvikvm(1233): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 5338: Lua/com/sadesign/aligorex/MainActivity;.getActionBar ()Landroid/app/ActionBar;
02-27 07:25:54.549: D/dalvikvm(1233): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-27 07:25:54.549: D/dalvikvm(1233): VFY: dead code 0x0005-000b in Lua/com/sadesign/aligorex/MainActivity;.setTitle (Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Там вроде написано, что нужно добавить support library. Что, с support library оно не работает?

Comment: Библиотека присутствует. Скриншот выложила.

Comment: в манифесте в minSdkVersion у вас что указано?

Comment: @Yura Ivanov 
android:minSdkVersion="7"

Comment: @Imire, как не работает? не запускается или падает приложение? на 10ке у себя запускаю нормально (7ки нет, сорри). Если падает, давайте logcat.

Comment: Там нужно action bar из support library v7. Инструкцию-то я нашел, [вот][1]. А вот заставить её работать не смог. Может у кого получится. Эклипс ругается. Я бы тоже хотел знать как запустить пример на api 7.




  [1]: https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: для бокового меню актион бар не нужен, скачайте пример гугла

Comment: @Yura Ivanov логи выложила, так же добавила скриншоты. Программа в эмуляторе запускается, но не полностью. 

@gadfil я и скачала пример гугла, на андроиде 4.0 все запускается как нужно, на андроиде 2.3.3 такой результат.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все верно, для работы примера с ActionBar нужен API 11, либо support library v7. Если использовать support library, то нужно вызовы getActionBar() заменить на getSupportActionBar() и наследовать activity от ActionBarActivity (тоже из v7).

В случае, если вы используете ActionBarSherlock или вовсе не используете никакой action bar, для работы Navigation Drawer достаточно support library v4.

N.B. Пример по ссылке всегда предназначен для тех, кто хочет запустить его на самой свежей версии API (в которой все Activity уже имеют action bar). Поэтому чтоб заработало на более ранних версиях приходится допиливать молотком, на той странице кстати инструкция есть, но она размазана по статье.

Comment: +1, лучше всего использовать ActionBarSherlock. Проблем настройкой проэкта в разы меньше. Да и допиливать ничего не нужно.